# jquery autocomplete dropdownlist width 100%

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an ASP.NET DropDownList using jquery ui autocomplete as shown [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

It works nice, but I would like to set the width of the control to 100%.

To do this, I've tried to add this code after the call to `$("#myDropDownList").combobox();`

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("custom.combobox", [...]);
    $("#cmbSupplier").combobox();
    $(".custom-combobox-input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".custom-combobox-input").css("width", "100%;");
});
```

While the `background-color` css works, the `width` css does not change anything.

Is there a way to set the input result width to 100%?

EDIT: Sample HTML mark up

```
    <table style="width: 300px;"><tr>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSupplier" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    </tr></table>
```

You can see the result in the next image. It gets the background, but not the width. I would like to fill all the space with the DropDownList (in this case, the 300px of the parent table).

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, I could set the with to 100% by setting the with to the input and also to the parent element.

```
$(".custom-combobox-input").css("background-color", "red");
$(".custom-combobox").css("width", "100%");
$(".custom-combobox-input").css("width", "100%");
```

But now this is the result. It overflows the padding and the button. Is there a way to solve it? It should fit all inside the table cell...

[image]

Comment: Please provide html mark up and small reproduction of the issue to start with. It's easy to find issues when there is more relevant code to inspect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, html mark up added.

Comment: May be just apply width on `asp:DropDownList`. I believe you're applying style on internal element which is already 100% of its parent.

Comment: Note that in the moment you call ("#cmbSupplier").combobox(); my DropDownList is set to display: none and it shows the new generated autocomplete control. This one should be the control to apply the desired style. As you can see the red background works..

Comment: you're right. background color works, so does the width. I can see the input `custom-combobox-input` within dropdown with red color is full width respective to its parent. What you need here is to set the width of parent to 100% so it spans across the `td`. So try setting width on dropdown list and it should be carried over by ui widget to persist the styling. have you tried setting width on dropdown list? if so, what was the output?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by setting the width to both elements and adding this line:

```
$(".custom-combobox").css("width", "100%");
$(".custom-combobox-input").css("width", "100%");
$(".custom-combobox-input").width($(".custom-combobox-input").width() - 53);
```